# Where-Object not filtering on ScriptBlock when stored in variable

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I want to filter a set of files in a folder with a where clause like so:

```
$fileParams = @{
    Path = C:\Files\*
    Include = '*.cs'
    Recurse = $true
}    
Get-ChildItem @fileParams | where {$_.Name -match `
    '^(?!Status|Answer|Question).*'}
```

This works as expected.

**Problem**

My problem is that I want to store the regular expression in a config file and have it passed into my function. This means the filter script has to start as a string. When I do both of the following to try to get PowerShell to execute the filter script, it doesn't filter:

```
Option 1:
[String]$Filter = '^(?!Status|Answer|Question).*'
Get-ChildItem @fileParams | where {$_.Name -match $Filter}

Option 2:
$filterText = '{$_.Name -match "^(?!Status|Answer|Question).*"}'
[ScriptBlock]$filter = [ScriptBlock]::Create($filterText)
Get-ChildItem @fileParams | where -FilterScript $filter
```

I have taken what is stored in the variable and pasted it in for the variable and the files are filtered down as expected.

How can I go about filtering these files down so that the details of the filter are stored in a config file? I've got to believe there is an option I'm missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

```
$a='^(?!2008|2011|2012).*'
$a | out-file .\filter.config
$b = gc .\filter.config
Get-ChildItem @FileParams | where {$_.Name -match $b}
```

(My filter is different to match the files I have on my HD, but pattern is similar).

Can you elaborate on Option 1 not working ?

Comment: After looking at your example, I realized I was unnecessarily adding in quotes in my config. I probably should have just slept on the issue instead of posting a question. Thanks for the assistance.